# Does emojis/similes works in JSPDF?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Unable to export emojis in pdf I also tried by adding custom fonts but still not working.

Expected Output:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution on how to export emojis with jsPDF?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution for that so I skipped emojis using regex while exporting  @waanderer